# Google Sheets Query combining data source

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-query

I don't know why but when put two sources in QUERY command, I get #ARG! error. Can somebody tell me why?

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1jzhsqVD5oeokraoKcu4C2AnnlzBBVvbD_lONBKrgk-I/edit#gid=387365472

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cant ref to A, B [..] when merged input data use Col1, Col2 [..]

Comment: Yes, it actually works... I was convinced that I also checked with Col1... By the way, why not use "A,B" when both ranges have identical column names?